# How do I loop through my data which I receive per api

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, observable

So when I try to loop through data which I receive per api, I get this error:

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. >NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Here is my component where I try to loop through it (**main.component.html**):

`<app-editform [toDo$]="todo" *ngFor="let todo of cs.$todos"></app-editform>`

Here is the constructor of **main.component.ts**:

```
import {ConfigService} from '../service/config.service';

constructor(public cs : ConfigService) { 
}
```

Here is my **config.service.ts** file:

```
import {TodoService} from './todo.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

export class ConfigService {

    public $todos: Observable<TodoService[]>;

    constructor(private http:HttpClient) {
        this.getGlobalData();
    }

    public getGlobalData(): void {
        this.$todos = this.getToDoData();
    }

    public getToDoData(): Observable<TodoService[]> {
        return this.http.get<TodoService[]>(`${this.url}`);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's an observable, not an array. Have you tried `*ngFor="let todo of (cs.$todos | async)"`

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error says.
Angular only supports iterating over arrays.

I think you are missing the `| async` for converting your observable back to an array.

`<app-editform [toDo$]="todo" *ngFor="let todo of cs.$todos | async"></app-editform>`

Comment: Is `| async` also missing from your answer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't iterate to an `Observable`. You should subscribe to it to recover the **array** of `TodoService`. Try something like that:

```
public $todos :TodoService[];

// ..

public getGlobalData() {
    this.getToDoData().subscribe(result => this.$todos = result);
}
```

Or you can directly convert the `Observable` to an array using `async` in yout html:

```
<app-editform [toDo$]="todo" *ngFor="let todo of (cs.$todos | async)"></app-editform>
```